# I don't login in bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have a problem that I don't login to bluemix dashboard!

Display image below.

What's mean this error?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Same of [Sign up 404 page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967176/sign-up-404-page/35967424#35967424)

On IBM Bluemix status page has been published a notification for an issue on the platform

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

> IBM Bluemix Platform issue on US South region
>   IBM Bluemix users are getting an error when trying to log into the US South region through the web console UI and the CLI.
>   The operations team is investigating the issue and working toward a resolution. We apologize for the inconvenience

Incident started at 4:37AM UTC of March 13th

You could monitor the status page for the issue resolution
The other regions

United Kingdom: https://console.eu-gb.bluemix.net

Sydney: https://console.au-syd.bluemix.net

are working fine

Edit: incident resolved at 7:38 AM UTC (3:38 AM EST)

Comment: Thanks your help ! I tried to log in again, this time was successful. It is time to check the status page.
Thank you for your help.