# Sign up 404 page

Tags: ibm-cloud

Is anyone else getting a 404 page when trying to sign up for a bluemix account?
Here is the link to the website: https://console.ng.bluemix.net

Comment: You can use https://www.isup.me to check if a website is down, or is it just for you

Answer (score 2):

On IBM Bluemix status page has been published a notification for an issue on the platform

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

> IBM Bluemix Platform issue on US South region
>   IBM Bluemix users are getting an error when trying to log into the US South region through the web console UI and the CLI.
>   The operations team is investigating the issue and working toward a resolution. We apologize for the inconvenience

Incident started at 4:37AM UTC of March 13th

You could monitor the status page for the issue resolution
The other regions

United Kingdom: https://console.eu-gb.bluemix.net

Sydney: https://console.au-syd.bluemix.net

are working fine

Edit: incident resolved at 7:38 AM UTC (3:38 AM EST)